# How many subsets contain no 3 consecutive elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> How many subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ have no $3$ consecutive numbers ?

### My solution:

Inspired by [How many subsets contain no consecutive elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841575/677339) I decided to write recurrence: 
Let be set with numbers from $1$ to $n$ and let $A$ - subset of given set
$$ a_n = \underbrace{a_{n-1}}_{n \notin A} + \underbrace{a_{n-2}}_{n \in A , n-1 \notin A} + \underbrace{a_{n-3}}_{n \in A, n-1 \in A, n-2 \notin A} $$

After examining corner cases I use [iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) to write full recurrence:
$$ a_n = a_{n-1}+ a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + [n=0] + [n=1] + [n=2]$$
After multiplying by $x^n$ and summing by all $n$ I got generating function:
$$A(x) = x A(x) + x^2 A(x) + x^3 A(x) +1+ x + x^2 $$
$$A(x) = \frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x-x^2-x^3} $$
But how to solve this generating function to get coefficient with $x^n$?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial for the recursion is $x^3-x^2-x-1$ and that hasn't got [very pleasant roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%3Dx%5E2%2Bx%2B1), so there might not be a terribly good looking solution.

Comment: @lulu Before posting I also checked in mathematica so I am not sure if my approach is correct so decided to share that to forum with my explanation, maybe there is logical mistake there

Comment: Oh, I trusted your recursion.  But it looks correct...is there any reason you expected a pleasant solution?

Comment: This exercise comes from old exam, per task is about ~30 minutes so I wonder if there exists anything pleasant but I have doubts too...

Comment: Not sure your initial conditions are correct. You seem to have $a_1=1, a_2=2$ but that's not correct.  None of the $4$ subsets of $\{1,2\}$ contain $3$ consecutive terms

Comment: Your generating function is not correct.  Your function is $x + 2 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 6 x^4 + 11 x^5 + 20 x^6 + O(x^7)$ which is not correct.   But I do believe your recursion is correct.

Comment: I fixed problems with initial values

Comment: Now, I checked in wolfram, it is $1+2 x+4 x^2+7 x^3+13 x^4+24 x^5+44 x^6+81 x^7+149 x^8+274 x^9+504 x^{10}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$ which seems to be good?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.  For reference that is [A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073) on oeis.org and they don't provide a simple closed formula.

Comment: Ok @lulu, I think that it is enough, probably the target of that exercise was just found a recurrence and describe solution, please move your last comment to answer, I will marked that as 'best'. Thanks for help

Comment: You solved it, I just verified it.  You can post and accept your own solution (happens all the time).

Comment: But you helped mi find a bug which point me where the problem was and also shared a interesting link with statement that there are no closed formula (which I didn't know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The recursion:  $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\quad a_1=2\quad a_2=4 \quad a_3=7$$

has characteristic polynomial $$x^3-x^2-x-1$$ which doesn't have particularly pleasant roots, which means that there isn't a simple closed formula for the results.  The sequence $$\{a_n\}=\{2,4,7,13, 24, 44, 81,
\cdots \}$$ is part of [A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073) in oeis.org  and that link contains a lot of information on the sequence, though of course it does not present a simple closed formula.  Note that the characterization given there as the number of binary sequences of length $n$ for which the string $000$ does not appear is entirely equivalent the one given by the OP here, as each string corresponds to a subset (where a $1$ indicates that the entry is absent and a $0$ indicates that it is present).