# How many subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots , 10\}$ don't have two numbers difference between which is $2, 3$ or $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I probably need to use inclusion-exclusion lemma. The total number of subsets of a $10$ element set is $2^{10} = 1024$. Now I calculate the number of subsets for which the statement holds individually for $2, 3, 5$ (in that order): for $2$ it's $169$, for $3$ it's $200$ and for $5$ it's $243$.

To get the number of subsets of $S=\{1 \ldots,n\}$ with no two numbers difference between which is $m$ we'll divide all numbers form the $S$ into $m$ groups by their modulo $m$. After that we'll count number of subsets of these groups without two consecutive numbers (because difference between two consecutive numbers in these groups is exactly m). The number is actually $F_{r+2}$ if the group has $r$ elements.  See [How many subsets contain no consecutive elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841575/how-many-subsets-contain-no-consecutive-elements). Using product rule we multiply those to get the numbers I mentioned.

For example let's count it for $2$: we have groups $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ and $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$. Each has $5$ elements, so the answer is $F_7 \cdot F_7=169$.

However I struggle to find the number of intersections between those sets.

Comment: Please show us how you arrived at those numbers of subsets.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, I used a rather simple approach. To get the number of subsets of $S = \{1, \dots, n\}$ with no two numbers difference between which is $m$ we'll divide all numbers form the $S$ into $m$ groups by their modulo $m$. After that we'll count number of subsets of these groups without two consecutive numbers (because difference between two consecutive numbers in these groups is exactly $m$). The number is actually $F_{r+2}$ if the group has $r$ elements [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841575). Using product rule we multiply those to get the numbers I mentioned

Comment: For example let's count it for 2: we have groups $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$ and $\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$. Each has $5$ elements so the answer is $F_7 \cdot F_7 = 169$

Comment: It seems just about as much work to simply list all possibilities.

Comment: @Edward I don't know what you wanted to hide while erasing the whole question and changing the tags. Please let the question as it is since it has attracted answers. Also, don't pollute other tags.

Answer (score 2):

Counting the empty set, there are $53$ subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ for which no two elements differ by $2$, $3$, or $5$.

We start by defining an equivalence relation on nonempty admissible subsets by saying that two such subsets are equivalent if they are translates of each other. That is: If  $S=\{a_1, a_2, ...,a_k\}$, then $S\sim \{c+a_1, c+a_2,...,c+a_k\}$ for any integer $c$ for which all values stay within the set $\{1,...,10\}$. For instance, the admissible subset $\{1,7,8\}$ is equivalent to itself and to $\{2,8,9\}$ and to $\{3,9,10\}$.

Then every nonempty admissible subset is equivalent to one and only one admissible subset that includes $1$ as an element. For instance, the admissible subset $\{3,9\}\sim \{1,7\}$.

An admissible subset containing $1$, say $S=\{1,a_2, ...,a_k\}$, with $1<a_2<...<a_k$, will have $11-a_k$ subsets in its equivalence class.

Then it is fairly straightforward to list the admissible sets containing $1$, and how many sets are in their equivalence classes:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} \mbox{Subset with 1}& \mbox{Size of equivalence class} \\ \hline 
\{1\} & 10 \\
\{1,2\} & 9 \\
\{1,2,8\} & 3 \\
\{1,2,8,9\} & 2\\
\{1,2,9\} & 2\\
\{1,2,9,10\} & 1\\
\{1,2,10\} & 1\\
\{1,5\} & 6\\
\{1,5,9\} & 2\\
\{1,7\} & 4\\
\{1,7,8\} & 3\\
\{1,8\} & 3\\
\{1,8,9\} & 2\\
\{1,9\} & 2\\
\{1,9,10\} & 1\\
\{1,10\} & 1\\
\end{array}$$
This accounts for $52$ admissible sets. Including the empty set as admissible, gives the total of $53$ such sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet an other counting scheme.

Denote by $\Bbb S$ the power set of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Let $\Bbb S_k$ be the set of all $A\in \Bbb S$ so that if $a\in A$ then $a+k$ is not in $A$.

Denote by $\Bbb S_{jk}$ the intersection $\Bbb S_j\cap \Bbb  S_k$.

We try to count the elements in the intersection $\Bbb S_{235}
=\Bbb  S_2\cap \Bbb  S_3\cap \Bbb S_5$.

Consider a set $A\in \Bbb S_2$. It is of the shape $A_0\cup A_1$,
where
$A_0\subseteq\{0, 2, 4, 6, 8\}$ is the subset of even entries in $A$, and
$A_1\subseteq\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$ is the subset of odd entries in $A$.

The possibilities for $A_0$, $A_1$ are not many, only $F_7=13$, here are they
in two columns:

```
empty  empty
0      1    
2      3    
4      5    
6      7    
8      9    
04     15   
06     17   
08     19   
26     37   
28     39   
48     59   
048    159
```

We count now for each choice of $A_0$ the possibilities of a "good"
choice for
$A_1$, so that $A:=A_0\cup A_1$ is also in $\Bbb S_{35} =\Bbb S_3\cap\Bbb S_5$.
Here is the list:

```
A0     # A1 cases   Comment
----------------------------------------
empty  13           all A1
0       6           all A1 that avoid 3, 5
2       6           all A1 that avoid 5, 7
4       3           all A1 that avoid 1, 7, 9
6       3           all A1 that avoid 1, 3, 9
8       6           all A1 that avoid 3, 5
04      1           all A1 that avoid 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
06      2           all A1 that avoid 1, 3, 5, 9
08      6           all A1 that avoid 3, 5
26      1           all A1 that avoid 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
28      4           all A1 that avoid 3, 5, 7
48      1           all A1 that avoid 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
084     1           all A1 that avoid 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

So we count a total of
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
13 + 4\cdot 6 + 4 + 2\cdot 3 + 2 + 4\cdot 1 = 53
\qquad}
$$
possibilities to combine a choice of $A_0$ with one of an $A_1$
which deliver $A=A_0\cup A_1\in\Bbb S_{235}$.

---

*Computer check:* Sage code:

```
S = Subsets([1..10])

def has_difference(A, k):
    return True in [a - aa == k for a in A for aa in A]    # lazy

S2 = [A for A in S if not has_difference(A, 2)]
S23 = [A for A in S2 if not has_difference(A, 3)]
S235 = [A for A in S23 if not has_difference(A, 5)]

print(f"S2   has {len(S2):3} elements.")
print(f"S23  has {len(S23):3} elements.")
print(f"S235 has {len(S235):3} elements.")
```

And we obtain:

```
S2   has 169 elements.
S23  has  88 elements.
S235 has  53 elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inclusion-exclusion, but even the base case that you have done seems like quite a bit of work.

Clearly the empty subset and every singleton subset will do, yielding $11$ subsets. Suppose $A$ is such a subset with at least $2$ elements and let $a\in A$ be its least element. Then $A$ does not contain $a+2$, $a+3$ and $a+5$. Moreover $A$ contains at most one of $a+1$, $a+4$ and $a+6$, because $a+4=(a+1)+3$ and
$$a+6=(a+1)+5=(a+4)+2.$$
Similarly $A$ contains at most one of $a+7$ and $a+9$. So if $a+1\in A$ then
$$A\subset\{a,a+1,a+7,a+8,a+9\},$$
with $a+7$ and $a+9$ mutually exclusive. For $a=1$ we get $6$ such subsets, for $a=2$ we get $4$ subsets, for $a=3$ we get $2$ subsets and for $a\geq4$ we get just $1$, for a total of $18$ sets starting with $a$ and $a+1$.

If $A$ contains either $a+4$ or $a+6$, then we have either
$$A\subset\{a,a+4,a+8\}\qquad\text{ or }\qquad A\subset\{a,a+6,a+7\}.$$
We find a total of $8$ sets starting with $a$ and $a+4$, and a total of $7$ sets starting with $a$ and $a+6$.

We are left with subsets starting with $a$ and $a+k$ with $k\geq7$, of which there are very few. For $a=1$ we find $5$ such subsets, for $a=2$ we find $3$ such subsets, and for $a=3$ we find $1$ such subset for a total of  $9$ subsets.

Then the total number of such subsets is
$$11+18+8+7+9=53.$$

Comment: A check by brute force (exhaustive enumeration) shows the number of acceptable subsets is $53$ (including the empty set), so there seems to be something wrong with this answer.  (I did not down-vote it.)

Comment: @awkward Thanks for letting me know. I overcounted the sets starting with $a$ and $a+4$, somehow.